# js code to disable dates based on conditional check

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When user selects a date from Available Date, 24days followed by the date selected in Available dates is displayed in the Expire Date field, saturday and sunday dates are disabled.Please find the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ahyk735/1/)

I'm facing difficulty for the below two requirements.

1) when user selects a date in Available Date field, the expire date field should enable 24 days dates excluding Saturday and Sunday and should not show dates beyond today.i.e,**if user selects 2017-05-11 as Available Date,in Expire Date, dates should be enabled from 2017-05-11 to 2017-05-19**(saturday and sunday are disabled).

2)Expire Date field should be disabled, when user selects a date in Available Date field then only Expire Date field should be enable and user is allowe to select a date.

js code:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ["ui.bootstrap"]);

// create angular controller
demoApp.controller("demoController", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
        var today = new Date();
        $scope.AvailableDate = new Date();
        $scope.ExpireDate = new Date();
        $scope.dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
        $scope.availableDateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1,
            minDate: "2016-03-12",
            maxDate: today,
               dateDisabled: function(data) {
                var date = data.date;
                var mode = data.mode;
               return (mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ));
            }

        };
        $scope.expireDateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1,
            minDate: today,
            maxDate: "2017-06-12",
            dateDisabled: function(data) {
                var date = data.date;
                var mode = data.mode;
               return (mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ));
            }
        };
        $scope.availableDatePopup = {
            opened: false
        };
        $scope.expireDatePopup = {
            opened: false
        };
        $scope.ChangeExpiryMinDate = function(availableDate) {
            if (availableDate != null) {
                var availableDate = new Date(availableDate);
                var expiryMinDate = angular.copy(availableDate);
                expiryMinDate.setDate(expiryMinDate.getDate() + 28);

                $scope.ExpireDate = availableDate;
                $scope.expireDateOptions.minDate = availableDate;
                $scope.expireDateOptions.maxDate = expiryMinDate;
            } else {
                delete $scope.ExpireDate;
            }
        };
        $scope.ChangeExpiryMinDate($scope.AvailableDate);
        $scope.OpenAvailableDate = function() {
            $scope.availableDatePopup.opened = !$scope.availableDatePopup.opened;
        };
        $scope.OpenExpireDate = function() {
            $scope.expireDatePopup.opened = !$scope.expireDatePopup.opened;
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Your example : "if user selects 2017-05-11 as Available Date,in Expire Date, dates should be enabled from 2017-05-11 to 2017-05-19" doesn't match your requirement. Shouldn't it be 2017-06-02?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `ng-disabled`, you can check to see if the Available Date has been set first.

```
ng-disabled="!AvailableDate"
```

However, you are also preselecting today's date in the controller, so AvailableDate is prepopulated before the User's selection. Removing this means the User is forced to select an Available Date and you don't have to calculate the initial Expire Date by calling: `$scope.ChangeExpiryMinDate($scope.AvailableDate);`

The requirement was:

- Expiry Date is usually Available Date + 24 days.
- However, if this is beyond Today's date, then Expiry Date is Today's date.

We can use [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) to calculate which is smaller: Today's Date or the potential calculated date which is Available Date + 24 days:

```
expiryMinDate = new Date(Math.min(expiryMinDate.setDate(expiryMinDate.getDate() + 23), new Date()));
```

I have created an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/n12vfwph/11/

Comment: Your example jsfiddle is not working, throwing js exceptions. My another requirement was when user selects a date in Avaialble date 24 days excluding saturday and sunday's should be enabled in Expired Date field and should not exceed today's date. For example if user selects 2017-05-15 in Available Date , in expired Date field only till today's date the dates should be enabled.thanks.

Comment: Hi.  I believe your requirement is easy to solve, however, I'm finding it difficult understand. Could you provide an example:  If I selected 2017-02-01.  What dates are enabled in the Expiration Date Field?

Comment: If i selected 2017-02-01, expire date field should enable next 24 days . If user selects 2017-05-05 then in expire date field it should enable only till today as 24 days falls after today's date and in expire date the date field should not enable after today, hope you got my point.Thanks @user2340824

Comment: I completely understand now!  I have updated my example for this.

Comment: thanks, it's working.Appreciate your help @user2340824